# Can we detect that toString() is being called in response to a debugger request when the application is stopped?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints, tostring

I have code that uses toString() for testing unit test output against golden masters (expecting specific output).  At the same time, while I am debugging said unit tests, the output from toString() is somewhat terse and I would like more extensive/friendly information displayed in the debugger output (variable display, watches, etc.)  What I would like to do is detect that toString() is being called as the result of a debugger evaluation, rather than as a consequence of running in the normal code path.

I have tried dumping the stack and thread info when toString() is called.  It is always called in the same context (call stack and thread) that is being debugged.  There are no "special" methods being pushed onto the stack when toString() is called -- toString() appears, and then the "currently" executing method.

My current solution is changing the implementation of toString() on an as-needed basis.  It is tedious, though, and error-prone in the sense that if I forget to reset it before a complete unit test run, I will have many errors.

One potential solution is to get the stack frame just above the toString() call, get its file and line number, and check if there is a direct or implicit call to toString() on that line.  I think that detecting all situations that can create implicit calls is error-prone, so I'd rather not go down that road.

If it helps, I am running Java code in the IntelliJ IDEA debugger.

What I am hoping is that there is some API or technique that I have overlooked that can give me this info.

Comment: You want your program to behave differently while it is being debugged? Really? Think about this very carefully.

Comment: No, I don't want my program to behave differently when it is being debugged -- but that is what my current debugging techniques are requiring.  I want the debugger to display a superset of (and more friendly) output than what the unit tests require.  Effectively, I want the unit tests and the debugger to use different implementations.  Unfortunately, they both use toString() to do their work.  So, when I change the implementation to make debugging easier, then the unit tests are guaranteed to fail.

Comment: ***Never*** use `toString()` for application logic purposes.  `toString()` should be used only for logging and debugging, and it should be freely modifiable without any impact whatsoever on application logic.  If you have specific requirements for what `toString()` may and may not return, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @MikeNakis Where did I say that I was using it for application logic?  In this case, the _unit tests_ are used to verify that application logic was correct -- that correct data structures were created.  It's amazing the assumptions people make when answering questions, and even more amazing that they make dogmatic statements without remembering that every practice has practical and useful exceptions.  So... if you make such strong statements as you just did, you're doing it wrong.  :)

Comment: Let me rephrase the above: ***Never*** use `toString()` for application logic ***(or testing)*** purposes.   `toString()` should be used only for... and it should be freely...  If you have specific requirements... -- there, FTFY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider using the [Type Renderers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-data-type-renderers.html) feature in IntelliJ IDEA and disable `toString()` evaluation for the debugger.

Comment: Sweet!  A feature I didn't know existed.  Thanks!

It doesn't exactly answer the question posed, but it solves my problem.